# ros_gz_bridge does not publish on ros2 topic

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, gz-sim

I am running `ros_gz_bridge` to read some data from Gazebo, in particular I have run:

```
ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /model/x500_vision_0/odometry@nav_msgs/msg/Odometry[gz.msgs.Odometry

[INFO] [1706113773.667589591] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/x500_vision_0/odometry (gz.msgs.Odometry) -> /model/x500_vision_0/odometry (nav_msgs/msg/Odometry)] (Lazy 0)
```

The problem is that when I run

```
ros2 topic echo /model/x500_vision_0/odometry
```

I do not see any message published on the topic.

I have already checked that the name of the topic is correct, and when I run

```
gz topic -et /model/x500_vision_0/odometry
```

I can see the messages exchanged within Gazebo.

So why is the bridge not publishing the messages on the ROS2 network?

**EDIT:**

Some more info about my setup.

I am working with ROS2 Humble and with Gazebo Sim version 7.7.0:

```
 gz sim --version
Gazebo Sim, version 7.7.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2.0 License.
```

I have installed Gazebo trough the apt package provided with ros2:

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-ros-gz
```

The world that I am running is a custom world that includes some static objects and a quadrotor equipped with the odometry plugin.

It all run inside a Docker based on the image `osrf/ros:humble-desktop`

Comment: Can you provide more details about your system setup, such as Gazebo and `ros_gz` versions and how you installed them and which world you were running?

Comment: I edited my question adding some more details! I hope them to be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.
I thought I was working with Gazebo Fortress, but a software I was working with installed Gazebo Garden instead.

When I installed the `ros-gz-bridge` from the apt repository, it installed only the supported package that is officially supported by ROS Humble, which is the Gazebo Fortress one.

I installed the ros-gz-bridge from [sources](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/humble) and now the bridge is working as expected.